# NuGet can't resolve a dependency when installing ServiceStack.Caching.Azure

Tags: azure, servicestack, nuget, azure-caching

I'm attempting to install the Service Stack Azure Cache provider but I receive a NuGet error as follows.

```
  PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Caching.Azure
  Attempting to resolve dependency 'ServiceStack.Common (≥ 4.0.12)'.
  Attempting to resolve dependency 'ServiceStack.Interfaces (≥ 4.0.12)'.
  Attempting to resolve dependency 'ServiceStack.Text (≥ 4.0.12)'.
  Attempting to resolve dependency 'WindowsAzure.Caching (≥ 2.2.0.0)'.
  Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'WindowsAzure.Caching (≥ 2.2.0.0)'.
  At line:1 char:16
  + Install-Package <<<<  ServiceStack.Caching.Azure
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I've tried manually installing the WindowsAzure.Caching library before installing the Service Stack package but the problems remains.

I've also tried removing everything from the packages folder and using NuGet to restore packages but no joy.

All ideas welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue on a blank project.

Looking at the current version of [ServiceStack.Caching.Azure](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Caching.Azure/4.0.12) (at the time of this writing) there is a dependency `WindowsAzure.Caching (≥ 2.2.0.0)`. [WindowsAzure.Caching](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Caching) only has `1.7.0` but there is a [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching/) `2.2.0` which could be what the author of the NuGet-package meant (or there is a private feed containing `WindowsAzure.Caching 2.2.0`).

You will probably want to get in touch with servicestack as [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/9d1614e934b9445c4206fb4a2e85e6f9f73afb4b) seems to have broken the package dependency by adding the version without switching to the new package name. I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/892) for them that should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks Simon, look like mythz has picked up your pull request.  For everyone else it looks like this should be fixed should be in the next release.

Comment: Yeah, they reacted quite fast. Their [MyGet feed](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) already contains a fixed build of the package.